# Intellij IDEA setup: cannot resolve symbol println

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

Intellij is giving me this error for scala code:

```
    Cannot resolve symbol "println"
```

**Project Settings:**

Project SDK:

```
  Intellij IDEA Community Edition IC-141.2735.5(openjdk version "1.8")
```

Project Language Level:

```
  8 - Lambdas, type annotations etc.
```

**Platform Settings:**

SDKs:

```
   1.8   /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64

   IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition IC-141.2735.5
```

Global Libraries:

```
   scala-sdk-2.11.6
```

EDIT:

The compiler reports that println has multiple implementations:

```
    scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.6.jar
    scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.6.jar
```

What does this mean?

Comment: Can you show the class? Does it compile outside of intellij?

Comment: Hate to ask but I gotta. Did you add `System.out`?

Comment: looks like you're trying to compile scala code with a java compiler

Comment: @DavidPulse This is Scala, which I don't think requires that. **But**, as Reimus said, the compiler/IDE is Java so it wouldn't like Scala syntax.

Comment: You also need the Scala plugin for Intellij, not only the SDK.

Comment: Yea, that's not my area.

Comment: Same, but I googled it and found that you don't need `System.out`.

Comment: Adding system.out removes the IntelliJ warning. It compiles fine, but in the IDE it has warnings all over the place.  How can I verify the scala plugin is working? I downloaded it following the IDEA prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it's still relevant but I just had the same problem. For me, it worked to just re-add the Scala SDK under "Global Libraries": Delete it using the red minus sign and then, with the green plus sign, add Scala SDK again.

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Nurse extends Employee {
    public Nurse(boolean working, long id, String name, String department) {
        super(working, id, name, department);

        // here println can be resolved. Because it's inside of a function.
        System.out.println("Invoking constructor "); 
    }

   // System.out.println("Some messge "); // here println can't be resolved.
}
```